# How do I send NLTK plots to files?

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

I'm using NLTK to create dispersion plots and do a few other things. Trouble is, I have to manually close the window that creating a dispersion plot opens to get the code to continue running. How can I send the plot to a file and keep the script moving? I assume I'll have the same problem with other plots. I can see from the [NLTK source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/dispersion.html) that `dispersion_plot` already includes `pylab.show()` so maybe this isn't possible without writing my own plotting function?

Here's my code that stops at line 2 until I close the Python window that opens with the plot.

```
1 # do some analysis
2 disp_plot(days, key_terms)
3 diversity_table(days, "Day")
```

Here's the `disp_plot` function:

```
# dispersion plots for search terms
def disp_plot(texts, terms):
    concat_text = ''.join(texts.values())
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(concat_text)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)
    text.dispersion_plot(terms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by reassigning pylab.show to my own function.  You might do something like this:

```
import pylab

counter = 0
def filename_generator():
    global counter
    to_return = 'myfig{0}.png'.format(counter)
    counter += 1
    return to_return

def my_show():
    return pylab.savefig(filename_generator())
```

and change your disp_plot() to look like

```
def disp_plot(texts, terms):
    concat_text = ''.join(texts.values())
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(concat_text)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)
    pylab_orig_show = pylab.show
    pylab.show = my_show
    text.dispersion_plot(terms)
    pylab.show = pylab_orig_show
```

Some would argue about the global, but this is just a quick hack to get the library to do what you want.